# Flutter Android FCM notification custom sound is not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

I have two apps - Customer and Restaurant

While customer places the order it app sends fcm notification to restaurant app to notify on new order. Notification is going perfectly fine the issue here is sound even though I have added the sound attribute it still plays default sound for the notification in restaurant app.

This is the code on Customer app which executes when order is placed

```
var url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
      var header = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "key=$SERVER_KEY",
      };
      var request = {
        "notification": {
          "title": title,
          "body": message,
          "sound": "order_notification_sound"// Tried with "order_notification_sound.mp3" also
        },
        "priority": "high",
        'data': <String, dynamic>{'id': '1', 'status': 'done'},
        "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
        "to": token
      };

      var client = new http.Client();
      await client.post(Uri.parse(url), headers: header, body: json.encode(request));
```

**order_notification_sound.mp3 is placed in '../res/raw' directory in Restaurant app**.
I guess this way it should have worked, Please correct if my understanding is correct? I am new to this concept, Please let me know if anyone can help or need any more details if I have missed anything. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Have you added keep.xml file in your android/src/main/res/raw folder,Along with your audio file make sure to add this so Your audio does not gets stripped off while reducing app size (so called tree-shaking)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@drawable/*,@raw/order_notification_sound" />
```

And make sure to keep the audio length under 30 sec.

Comment: Yes I have tried that just now, But still it is giving the default sound only. My audio length is 12 sec

Comment: Make sure to clean the project and rebuild

Comment: Yes I tried it by cleaning and rebuild. I have published the app in playstore without this sound change, still wondering what could I be missing here. It would be something small at the end I know but not able to figure out somehow